# Printing a word Document within Python

Tags: python

I have a simple batch file here which will print a word document from the command line.

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\winword.exe" "p:\docs\daily checks.doc" /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit
```

I am trying to place this into a python script, I have managed to get the document to open by using

```
subprocess.Popen('"C:\\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\winword.exe"' '"P:\\docs\\daily checks.doc "')
```

I can't seem to get the `/mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit` part in the command, I have tried using `+'"/mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit"'` plus without the +, but then the document won't open.

Can you possibly help to see how I can print this word document, or is there a better way

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\winword.exe", "P:\\docs\\daily checks.doc", "/mFilePrintDefault", "/mFileExit"]).communicate()
```

Or, altenatively,

```
subprocess.Popen("'C:\\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\winword.exe' 'P:\\docs\\daily checks.doc' /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit", shell=True).communicate()
```

When you use `shell=True` the command is executed through a shell. This means that you have to pass a single string the same way as you would write the command in a shell, that is, with the quotes to prevent arguments with spaces to be splitted.

When you use `shell=False` (the default value), the command isn't executed through a shell. This means that you've to split the arguments yourself. The way you do this, is passing a list with all the arguments. In this case, no extra quoting is needed because the list elements already provide this information.

Comment: Perfect that worked, thanks very much for the quick response and the help.  Spot on!

Comment: The /mFileExit flag doesn't work for Word 2013. I need to close the file manually before my script continues.

Answer (score 0):

try using the following:

```
subprocess.Popen('"C:\\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\winword.exe" m"P:\\docs\\daily checks.doc" /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit')
```

`Popen` expects a complete string or a list of args, basically type what you'd type into the shell into `Popen` and it will work.

the [documentation on Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) states:

> args should be a string, or a sequence of program arguments.