# Printing MS Word .docx from PyQt GUI

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

## What I've got

I've built a GUI that populates a MS Word file with text and saves it. I was asked to include a function that makes it possible to directly print the output from the GUI.
When printing just a string object the following code works as intended:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *

def func_print_short(obj_str):

    print_content = QTextEdit()
    print_content.setText(obj_str)

    dlg_print = QPrintDialog()

    if dlg_print.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
        print_content.document().print_(dlg_print.printer())
```

## What I'm trying to achieve

Trying to use the same routine with a MS Word file I ended up with the following code snippet, not being able to figure out how to properly send the document to the printer.

```
import docx

def send_to_printer(doc):

    # -- datatype conversions --
    print_content = doc        

    dlg_print = QPrintDialog()

    if dlg_print.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
        print_content.document().print_(dlg_print.printer())
```

As expected, this doesn't work as the printer can't handle the data it receives. Unfortunately, I found a similar question on printing a PDF file from a GUI [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262274/pyqt-printing-raw-pdf), which is why I suppose that what I want to achieve might not be possible either without some workaround.

I've also found a post on printing MS Word documents [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413207/printing-a-word-document-within-python). However, I don't want to save it somewhere first to be able to print it.

## My questions

Is there a way to print the document directly from the GUI? Any suggestions how to convert the document into the right format? Or is there a better solution as temporarily saving it and using `subprocess` for the rest?

Thank you in advance!